# Cannot include certain header files using the Visual C++ compiler

Tags: c, visual-c++, include, winsock

Hello I'm getting into Winsock programming in C. I believe that in order for me to access the  (or any other header related to Winsock for that matter) header file I have to have Visual C++ 2010 installed and set it as my default compiler. So I download it, and in CodeBlocks I set it to my compiler. I run some Winsock code and I get this message:

```
C:\Users\Jared\Documents\Test.c|6|fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winsock2.h': No such file or directory|
```

I also get this message for including 'winsock.h' and 'windows.h'. This has something to do with the Visual C++ compiler. I try installing Visual C++ 2008 and use it as my compiler and get the same message. I then read that I have to install microsoft's SDK. I download and install it and it gets an error saying that I can't install it (this is the .Net framework 4.0 version). I then try the 3.5 version and it installs fine but my compiler still can't find the header files. I have the .net framework 4.0 so I don't see  the problem. I also read that I have to include some header files in Visual C++ by going to Tools>Options>Projects and Solutions>VC++ Directories and I get the following message:

```
"VC++ Directory editing in tools > options has been deprecated."
```

Visual C++ 2010 no longer supports this feature. Does anyone have a solution or can help me with this?

Long story short: I cannot include 'winsock.h', 'winsock2.h', or 'windows.h' using the Visual C++ 2010 compiler.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual C++ 2010 it is recommended to use property sheets instead of this kind of global directory settings editing.  You need to edit the user settings property sheet (probably `Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props`) in your AppData folder.  You can do it in the UI through the Property Manager via View->Property Manager and browsing for that sheet.

However, I think you should have `$(WindowsSdkDir)include` in Include Directories if you have it installed correctly.

Comment: Visual Studio is the most helpful compiler if its working perfectly. But if its not god save that poor soul. Nothing short of a format helps.